# multiple cookie names with same name on different paths

Tags: weblogic, session-cookies, jsessionid

About this issue I read that the browser sends the cookies as follow

**The more specific the path, the higher the precedence**

I have two cookies in browser

```
jsessionid=avalue domain some.example.com
jsessionid=bvalue domain.example.com
```

when i request for http://some.example.com these cookies will be sent to server in the order of

```
jsessionid=avalue
jsessionid=bvalue
```

am i right?

and assuming that request is welcomed by Weblogic server, how weblogic reacts to this situation?

as you know jsession id is used to determine the session id in weblogic. this is a really critical issue for me.

Thanks.

Comment: as i debug from firebug, firefox sends jsessionid=bvalue first and then jsessionid=avalue... i am really getting mad...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that more specific the cookie path, the higher the precedence. However, in your case, the difference is the domain between two cookies, not path. The precedence based on other attributes, including the domain, is unspecified, and may vary between browsers. This means that if you have set cookies of the same name against “.example.org” and “some.example.org”, you can’t be sure which one will be sent back. http://www.sitepoint.com/3-things-about-cookies-you-may-not-know/

**Edit based on comments:**

I would recommend you using two different cookie-names if your have two war deployed together. The default session cookie name is jsessionid, but it is configurable in the `weblogic.xml`.

```
<session-descriptor>
   <cookie-name>jsessionid_app1</cookie-name>
</session-descriptor>
```

Comment: Thanks. I visited that link before I post here. You are right, I missed the path part. I also read the source code of Chrome and Firefox and i saw that there is no quarente which one will be sent first from the browser if the paths are same and in my case unfortunately they are same. Now my question is, i have the sessionid of main domain session in this case, is there any way to invalidate this session from another context? 2 wars are on the same weblogic server...

Comment: Also note that as of Servlet 3.0, you can also specify the name and path of the cookie in the standard web.xml : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/SessionCookieConfig.html